# How to open a Butterflylabs miner?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, butterfly-labs

How to open a [Butterfly 5GH/s miner](https://products.butterflylabs.com/5-gh-s-bitcoin-miner.html) and replace the fan? I don't see any screws at the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the paddings from bottom and open screws under them.